# Php curl post from live server to local ip

Tags: php, php-curl

I have a live server and an access point device. I authenticate the device with the live server with a normal HTML form post, which is working like this:

```
<form action="http://device_local_ip/" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="cmd" name="cmd" value="authenticate"><br><br> 
  <input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="test02"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="test02"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

However, I want to use php curl post from live server to local device IP - is it possible?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that a live server will be able to see a private IP in your local network unless you have set up some sort of DNS and allowed connections through your router.

Comment: i understand for example basically html posting working its firstly html post redirect device ip after the posting  its working how i can do this with curl?

Comment: "redirect device ip after the posting its working"...that's because it's your **browser** which contacts the device IP during a redirect. And if your browser is on the same local network as the device, then it can find it. But cURL is running on the **server**, and the server is outside your local network so it cannot see the device.

Comment: As Dave says, to make that work you'd need to set up dynamic DNS to point to your router's public IP, and then allow port forwarding on inbound connections to your router, to forward a connection from the router to the device. But of course that involves a security risk because you are allowing inbound connections to your network. You'd better hope this "device" (whatever it is) has good security and allows authentication etc.

Comment: i have multiple devices and have many location i cannot open the port as you say i have to do browser contacts but i don't want use html form post  you have any idea?

Comment: The only solution is to open the port, or to put the device onto the public internet instead of your local network. Even the HTML form post method would not work if you were using a computer which is not connected to your local network.

Comment: no i tested it working
because device accept post when i put external ip in device

Comment: "when i put external ip in device"...what do you mean by that exactly? It doesn't make sense. `http://device_local_ip/` is not accessible from outside your network, there is no exception to that.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag1r9.png @Adyson Please check this when i put access url device auto redirect to url and allow posting from url  you understand me what do mean?

Comment: Right. So your device has the ability to be configured with an external URL. Why didn't you mention this at the start of your question??

Comment: We assumed that because you were asking about whether it's possible to do it from cURL, that there was a problem with accessing a local URL from the server code. We didn't think that you just hadn't bothered to try yet. Did you actually try to use cURL to contact that Access URL and find a specific problem?

Comment: yes i mistake sorry and also for example when connect to device after the redirect access url and open the dns  captive-2019.aio.cloudauth.net from device after i post 
http://captive-2019.aio.cloudauth.net/cgi-bin/login with postman and html form post 
no have any problems  but cUrL post i have errors Error:Could not resolve host: captive-2019.aio.cloudauth.net

Comment: Maybe there is a firewall or other restriction on the server which prevents it making (certain kinds of) outbound request from the server itself. Is it a shared hosting account? You should contact the hosting support team to ask them if there is a network issue.

Comment: However it must be said, I just tried to follow the link to http://captive-2019.aio.cloudauth.net/cgi-bin/login and it appears that the domain does not exist. It's not clear how it's possible for you to access it but not others - unless maybe it is not properly registered on all DNS servers across the internet.

Comment: The other possibility is there is a mistake in your cURL code, but since you didn't show it, we cannot help you with that.